# how to solve: The group_list function accepts a group name and a list of members

Tags: python

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = ___
  return ___

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:"
```

Comment: This is a trivial exercise in using string formatting and `', '.join(...)`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing exercise, please show some effort: did you try anything, what output do you get, what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = ', '.join(users)
  return group + ': ' + members
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string.join()` method works well here. Get the members out of the input and into a list, and define a separator:

```py
members = [x for x in users]
separator = ", " # Since we want commas in our string at the end
```

From here, get the members out of the list and into a string:

```py
memstring = separator.join(members)
```

From here, you can use string formatting to get the output how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = ', '.join(users)
  return group + ': ' + members

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:"
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26967023)

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = ", ".join(users)
  return "{}: {}".format(group, members)

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_list(group, users):

    L = users

    return ("{}: ".format(group) + " ".join(L))


print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"]))

print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"]))

print(group_list("Users", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_list(group, users):
members = "{}:{}".format(group, " ".join(users) )
return members

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be 
"Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be 
"Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_list(group, users):
  return f"{group}: {', '.join(users)}"

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = "{group} : {users}".format(group = group,
users = ", ".join(users))
  return members

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) 
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) 
print(group_list("Users", ""))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```py
def group_list(group, users):
    members = "{}: {}".format(group, ", ".join(users) )
    return members
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).